# Flex 4 utc date time format problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

here are my functions they work fine when timeoffset is  round number(1,2,3,4...),but when is 3.5(3:30), 4.5(4:30) it doesnt work.
Can someone help me with this :

```
private function init_vars():void
            {
timeZoneOffset = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.clock_time_zone; // I load this with js
                timeZoneOffset = 5,50; // just for test
            }

            private function tick(event:TimerEvent):void 
            {                   
                var local: Date = new Date();

                var utc: Date = new Date(local.getTime() + (local.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));

                var utcTime:Number=utc.getTime();




                var new_offset_date:Number = utcTime + ((3600000) * timeZoneOffset);
                var new_date:Date = new Date(new_offset_date);              
                currentTime = new Date(new_date);
                showTime(currentTime); // another function just to display time                                 
            } 


private function showTime(time:Date):void
            {
                seconds = time.getSeconds();
                minutes= time.getMinutes();
                hours= time.getHours();

                            //rotate
                this.secondsPointer.rotation = (seconds * 6) - 90;
                this.minutesPointer.rotation = (minutes * 6) - 90;              
                this.hoursPointer.rotation = (hours * 30) + (minutes * 0.5) - 90;
                this.secondsPointer.visible = true;
                this.minutesPointer.visible = true;
                this.hoursPointer.visible = true;                           
            }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the function?  What are the expected results?  And what are you seeing?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com funcstion should calculate time depending on time zone offset. For example for mumabai timezone offset is 5.30 hours and for New York is 10hours - for example.Now it display like timezone offset is set to 5 not to 5hours and 30 minutes

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do this.  Doesn't the date class already have localization features built in?  Initialize and store everything in UTC time and then just display it using a date formatter.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I load timezone offset with js,take a look at my edit. On different timezone offset I display different time.But for 5hours and 30 min it is not working

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to manage to work if timezone offset is not round number like(1,2,3,4 hours),than when is 1hour and 30minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked fine. I just traced `currentTime` because I didn't have your `showTime` function, is it possible that the bug is in that function?

I would recommend to try something like the following if you can:

```
date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() + hoursDifference); //5
date.setUTCMinutes(date.getUTCMinutes + minutesDifference); //30
```

Modifying dates using the time in milliseconds, depending on how/where/when you actually use the application might create weird bugs in case of daylight savings. And you don't want to deal with a bug that might happen only twice a year in only certain countries of the world.

Comment: hi @Gevorg Thank you for the answer, I have update my code with showCurrent time function. And I will try the way you have recommend and will let you know,did that help.Tnx